# Eclipse PHP PHPUnit 10.4.2 - cannot launch phpunit tests (port address 7478) accept timed out

Tags: php, eclipse

I try to run a PHPunit test in Eclipse, the end result is no test, but this in the console:
PHPUnit 10.4.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

```
Unknown option "--printer"
```

And after that an error with:

```
cannot launch phpunit tests (port address 7478) accept timed out
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bad news** 
Eclipse PDT PHPUnit Tests plug-in supports only versions from 4~9 only in version [Eclipse PDT 8.2.0.202311292129](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/php-development-tools)

**Good news**
Plan to add PHPUnit10 support for PDT 8.3 (Eclipse 2024-03)
[Source: Eclipse Community Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1114196&goto=1862825&#msg_1862825)

**Solution with older Eclipse PDT** 
Is to downgrade used PHPUnit phar to version 9, ie. [phpunit-9.6.16.phar](https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-9.phar), 
[PHPUnit 9 announcement](https://phpunit.de/announcements/phpunit-9.html) 
[List of PHPUnit supported versions and PHP compatibility](https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html)

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded to version 9 and problem was solved. I read somethings about version 10 that printing to console is removed in this version, i assume that Ecplipse doesn't work correct with PhPunit then

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the PHPUnit command the Eclipse PHP plugin issues to remove unknown option.

The command was probably written for the older version of PHPUnit and this option is no longer supported.

Comment: where to do that and what to adjust?

Answer (score 0):

I had very same problem when running PHPUnit tests higher than `phpunit-9.6.16.phar`, ie. `phpunit-10.1.3.phar` and `phpunit-11.0.3.phar` the Eclipse PDT IDE shows following output:

> `Unknown option "--printer"`

in the `Console` view.

The solution that worked for me was as simple as unchecking single option in the PHPUnit Run configuration.

**Solution:**

1. Open Eclipse menu > Run > Run Configuration
2. Highlight your test in the list of tests under `PHPUnit` section on left panel
3. Switch to `Common` tab

   1. find section `Standard Input and Output`
   2. **uncheck** the option `[ ] Allocate console (necessary for input)`
   3. [Apply] and [Run]

Now you will have the `console` view empty however the `PHPUnit` view will fill with graphical results of your tests.

**Additional setting:**

Note that I have:

- defined the global `PHPUnit Phar` in Eclipse menu > Window > Preferences > PHP > Tools > PHPUnit
- defined the global `Runtime PHP` in  Eclipse menu > Window > Preferences > PHP > Installed PHPs
- defined the `PEAR` library

  - local for the PHP project in Project Explorer right click the PHP project > Properties > PHP > Source Paths > Include Path > Libraries tab > [New...]
  - global for Eclipse in Eclipse menu > Window > Preferences > PHP > Source Paths > Include Path > Libraries tab > [Add Library...] > User Library > [Configure] > [New...]
  - continue for both cases:

    - User library name: PEAR
    - [x] Add to environment (added to the script environment paths)
    - [OK], [Apply and Close], [Finish], [Apply and Close]
  - 

Of course make sure your PDT or at least the is up to date via Eclipse menu > Help > Check for updates

Comment: argh, you may ignore the post since it is not a working solution (keeping it here as reference and I will update it later). [Eclipse PDT](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/php-development-tools) with **PHPUnit Tests plug-in** supports only versions from **4~9** only! So versions 10+ are not supported (yet).